# Is there a way to shorten this script?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, scripting, ssrs-2008, case

Can anyone please help me figure out a more convenient and efficient (shortest) way of writing the below script? The reason I'm doing this is because I will end up using the script on SSRS.

On SSRS, there will be two parameters and both are set to take blank values.

If the user running SSRS indicated only the Starting date parameter, then my report should give any date >= the starting date.

If the user put dates on both @startingdate and @endingdate, my script will search only those that are between @startingdate and @endingdate.

Do you guys kinda get what I'm trying to accomplish?  I have an SSRS report similar to this scenario but it's very cumbersome to update because if I update one of the statement, I would have to do it on the other ones.  Also the script is big and repetitive because of this.

If you could help me figure out a better way to do shorten or make it less cumbersome to code, please let me know, thanks!

Below is a sample script that I use:

```
DECLARE @STARTINGDATE
DECLARE @ENDINGDATE

SET @STARTINGDATE = '10/01/2013'
SET @ENDINGDATE = '10/05/2013'

CASE 
   WHEN @STARTINGDATE <> '' AND @ENDINGDATE <> '' 
    SELECT * FROM SALESTABLE
    WHERE SALESDATE BETWEEN @STARTINGDATE AND @ENDINGDATE
   END

   WHEN @STARTINGDATE = '' AND @ENDINGDATE = ''
    SELECT * FROM SALESTABLE
   END

   WHEN @STARTING <> '' AND @ENDINGDATE = ''
    SELECT * FROM SALESABLE
        WHERE SALESDATE >= @STARTINGDATE
   END

   WHEN @ENDINGDATE <> '' AND @STARTINGDATE = ''
    SELECT * FROM SALESABLE
        WHERE SALESDATE <= @ENDINGDATE
   END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Smells like user input validation... and that is not something to leave to the DBMS

Comment: Since you're setting start and end date explicitly, all you really need is this: `SELECT * FROM SALESTABLE WHERE SALESDATE BETWEEN @STARTINGDATE AND @ENDINGDATE`. The rest of your `CASE` won't execute. If I've missed something please update your question.

Comment: R u using mySQL or SQL Server???

Comment: @astander - I'm using SQL Server 2008 (Developer Edition)

Comment: @MostyMostacho - Yes I agree, I do plan to convert the script in SSRS where users will have parameters to select how they want the script to run.

Comment: @Rony - I'm using SQL Server 2008 (Developer Edition)

Answer (score 0):

what if u use IF ELSE Statement?

```
IF @STARTINGDATE IS NOT NULL AND @ENDINGDATE IS NULL

SELECT * FROM SALESTABLE WHERE SALESDATE >= CONVERT(DATE,@STARTINGDATE,103)

ELSE IF @STARTINGDATE IS NOT NULL AND @ENDINGDATE IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM SALESTABLE WHERE SALESDATE >= CONVERT(DATE,@STARTINGDATE,103)

AND SALESDATE<DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,@ENDINGDATE,103))

ELSE

SELECT * FROM SALESTABLE
```

References http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/783c03/12

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if StartingDate and EnddingDate dates are string. Using StartingDate and EnddingDate as text you will loose the date picker functionality in SSRS. Anyway here is a method to shorten the above script

```
Select * FROM SalesTable
Where SalesDate between 
CASE WHEN @StartingDate = '' THEN SalesDate ELSE @StartingDate END
AND CASE WHEN @EndingDate = '' THEN SalesDate ELSE @EndingDate END
```

**Method 2**
If StartingDate and Endding date are dateTime. Use this method:
FYI: SSRS doesn't allow *Blank values* for *DateTime* parameters. It only allows NULL.

First **create two parameters** StartingDate and EndingDate and check the Allow NULL value.

[image]

Your **Dataset query** will be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM SalesTable
Where (SalesDate IS NULL OR @StartingDate IS NULL) 
OR (SalesDate between ISNULL(@StartingDate, SalesDate)
AND  ISNULL(@EndingDate, SalesDate))
```

Assign you dataset parameters to report parameters

[image]

Now your are good to go.

[image]

Comment: Nice catch. Fixed the CASE syntax.